# VS for Mac 2017 building with .NET Core SDK instead of Mono

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-mac

I have several solutions that target some combination of .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Core 2.1. I have the latest .NET Core 2.1 SDK installed.

When I build them via Visual Studio for Mac, I notice it is using the Mono build tools instead of `dotnet` such as `csc.exe`:

```
Target CoreCompile:
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Roslyn/csc.exe
```

Is there an option or some other property needs changed so that it can use the SDK instead of the Mono tools?

Comment: Mono build tools? You mean MSBuild (which is what Mono uses...`xbuild` is deprecated). Now when we are talking about the newer Core/dotnet/2.x, that is built on top of msbuild, i.e. a `dotnet restore` is just calling `msbuild /t:Restore ...` So no matter if you start the build via a `dotnet` cmd, msbuild is doing the "work"

Comment: @SushiHangover its using the mono c# compiler.

Comment: `csc.exe` is Roysln, the deprecated Mono compiler is/was `mcs`

Comment: @SushiHangover alright, but why is it using the mono copy, not the one part of the .net core sdk?

Comment: As far as I know, that is "just" how VS4M does it default directory/search mappings that are supplied to msbuild, I've never had a problem with that as the same version of csc is just csc, now if you need a different version, that might be a problem. I have a dozen+ versions of Mono/msbuild/csc/... installed on my Mac and thus use MSbuild's properties such as `CscToolPath` to override those default paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to use dotnet for building within Visual Studio for Mac. It uses msbuild. If you really want to do that you would need to bypass the built-in support and use of msbuild that VS Mac provides.

VS Mac uses msbuild that ships with Mono because it supports more target frameworks (e.g. Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android) than the .NET Core SDK's MSBuild does. Note that VS on Windows takes a similar approach where it uses a desktop MSBuild to run builds and does not use dotnet build.

However Mono's MSBuild still uses the various MSBuild sdk target files that are shipped with the .NET Core SDK. There is an MSBuild sdk resolver that ships with Mono that allows the .NET Core SDK msbuild targets to be found and used.

Also note that Mono's MSBuild includes some parts of the .NET Core SDK so it can compile .NET Standard projects without needing the .NET Core SDK.